# Cannot Parse Through the SOAP response by using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, soap, transformation

I am new in XSLT, I want to generate an xml from a soap response, i am failing to parse through the soap response and fetch the data from the tag due to namespace issues.

My input :

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ProcessResponse xmlns="KeyIntgration">
        <ProcessResult xmlns="">
            <AccessId xmlns="KeyIntgration">paul</AccessId>
            <TransactionId xmlns="KeyIntgration">abcd</TransactionId>
            <Payload xmlns="KeyIntgration">
                <DeclaredValue>8.00</DeclaredValue>
            </Payload>
        </ProcessResult>
    </ProcessResponse>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Here is my XSL file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
   xmlns:k="KeyIntgration/"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   exclude-result-prefixes="s xsd xsi k">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <rate>
        <xsl:value-of
            select="s:Envelope/s:Body/k:ProcessResponse/k:ProcessResult/k:Payload/k:DeclaredValue/text()" />
    </rate>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My Output is coming as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <rate/>
```

My expected Output is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <rate>8.00</rate>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Fix your namespace for `xmlns:k="KeyIntgration"` (no `/` at the end).
2. ProcessResult has not namespace (because of empty xmlns - `<ProcessResult xmlns="">`)
3. Between Payload and DeclaredValue there are some more elements. Use `//` (or add explicitly all elements).

Try:

```
  <xsl:value-of
     select="s:Envelope/s:Body/k:ProcessResponse/ProcessResult/k:Payload//k:DeclaredValue/text()" />
```